# Losing UTF-8 encoding after sencha app build in Sencha Cmd

Tags: javascript, extjs, encoding, utf-8, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to build my application with sencha cmd 6.0 and ext 6.0, but I have this problem since ext 5 with sencha cmd 5.0. What is happening is that my application in build folder is losing the special characters, like 'ç', 'é', anyone with this problem ?

Comment: This could be a problem with Sencha CMD, try updating it to the latest version (it is backwards compatible). I just tried with CMD 6.0.1 and it encodes the sentence "Essa area é usada para navegação, por exemplo, para um component "tree"." just fine.

Comment: got it, but i've been using all versions of cmd, and no one works, installing and uninstalling, clearing the registers with ccleaner, etc.

Comment: i tryed to do the following trick, replacing this line on "\u00E0\u00E2\u00E9\u00E8\u00EA\u00EB\u00EE\u00EF\u00F4\u00F9\u00FB\u00FC\u00FF\u00E7\u00E6\u0153" on file unicode-escapes.json from sencha cmd, an user from sencha forum said, that this line will build the characters àâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ, doesn't work :(

Comment: I also had this issue as I need to encode German Alphabets lie öüäß. I was using Sencha Cmd v5.1.2.49 but then I switched to Sencha Cmd v5.1.3.61 and it worked for me,

Comment: i'm using the latest version of cmd. i'm trying to build in a linux VM

Comment: Backing here to say that not building in latest version of ubuntu the problem is resolved. I Don't know more what to do :/

Comment: My friends, i solved my problem adding this code in first line of all js files of my project //@charset ISO-9959-1

Comment: The charset //@charset ISO-9959-1 was doing warning on sencha cmd, the right is //@charset UTF-8

So, the solution, is add //@charset UTF-8 in js files :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charset //@charset ISO-9959-1 was doing warning on sencha cmd, the right is //@charset UTF-8 So, the solution, is add //@charset UTF-8 in js files :D